# How to make lambda wait for callback?

Tags: node.js, async-await, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm creating an AWS lambda function that is supposed to regularly backup an AppSync API on S3 (it is fired by a CloudWatch schedule rule).
It's based on a class that, for each API passed as the function args (using environment variables) runs a backup job for each element of the API.

If I run it using only node, it works without any issue.

However, when I deploy or test locally using the serverless framework (`serverless deploy` and `serverless invoke local -f backup`), the execution stops at the first asynchronous instruction in a scope other than that of the handler function, whether I use a callback, a Promise.then() or the async/await syntax.

I've considered, running multiple lambda functions for each part of the backup operation, but then I would lose the shared context, which I need to ensure that every part of the backup is done correctly.

In `handler.js`

```
  // for testing purposes
    // works, waits 5 seconds and execute the rest of the code
    console.log("here1");
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
    console.log("here2");
    const allBackups = apiIds.map(apiId => new Backup(apiId));
    allBackups.map(backup => backup.start());
```

> Result => 
>   here1
>   [5 seconds wait]
>   here2

However, if I call a function that uses the asynchronous code, such as the `start` method of the `Backup` class (in the required `Backup.js` file), the following happens:

```
async start() {
        try {
            console.log("here3");
            const data = await this.AppSync.getGraphqlApi({ apiId: this.apiId }).promise();
            console.log("here4");
```

> Result =>
>   here1
>   [5 seconds wait]
>   here2
>   here3
>   End of execution

I have all the required roles, and serverless reports no issues when deploying or invoking locally.

Here is my `serverless.yml` file:

```
service:  [name]

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10

functions:
  backup:
    handler: handler.backup
    environment:
     [env variables, they are parsed properly]
    timeout: 60
    event:
      schedule: [doesn't work as well, but it's not the issue here]
        name: daily-appsync-backup
        rate: cron(0 0 ** ? *)
        enabled: false
    role: [role]
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Could you please post the catch() part in the start() function? Could it be that this.AppSync.getGraphqlApi() throws an exception which has been caught but not printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I've found a solution, I just did this:

```
    const allBackups = apiIds.map(apiId => new Backup(apiId));
    await Promise.all(allBackups.map(async backup => backup.start()));
```

It din't work because it reached the end of the handler function and did not care that there was other callbacks waiting.
(I also learned that you could `await` an `async` function, and not just a Promise.)